# jquery sortable is not working in mobile device

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have used `jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js` for sortable items , It's working in desktop but it's not working in mobile device .

I have also include `jquery-ui.min` but still is not work in mobile.

I used following code for sort

```
$('.BLC_rotaion_ul').sortable({
    items: '> .sort',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    helper: "clone",
    scroll: true
});
```

if someone know about jquery ui.touch then please help me.

Comment: You will need to add more of the code implied. It is hard to help you with just that. Did you check if you have any CSS rules that can affect the mobile view?

Comment: Please provide more details for replication. What device? Browser? We will need to see a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve